# RESTful web services client parameters

Tags: rest

I have a RESTful service in c# which provides Get and Post methods. while testing the service I realized that if I change the parameter name of any of the parameters, the call contains null as its value. for example if the service is expecting an Employee object (which has only 2 properties; ID and Name) in its post method, the client should pass the parameter names as 'ID' and 'Name'; anything else will just fail. Am I correct in understanding that there is tight coupling between the names used in the service and names passed by the client which would mean the client has an advance knowledge of the service at design time. Is this not against RESTful principles? And why do we have WADL if the REST services should not expect clients to know the detailed description of the service?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think would be a way to let the client know how to build the resource represenation for a request? What would be "anything else" for the names of the parameters?

Comment: SOAP based services do not have this convention to follow rather the clients rely on proxy classes and WSDL. I thought the REST clients need not know 'anything' about the service contract at design time but it seems the client needs to know internal structure of the objects. In case we are passing 2 complex objects, for example Employee and Product to insert/post an order, the client should know the parameter names and class structure which is not very different from having a client side proxy class. That bit doesn't make it simpler than SOAP

Comment: How do we make the clients aware of this info. Is it through WADL?

Comment: The client doesn't need to know the "internal structure of the objects". But it needs to know the semantics of the resource represenations. That includes the names and types of represenation fields.